# How would I move SQL MSSQL.1 and MSSQL.2 location?

Tags: sql-server, installation-path

We have a SQL instance where the MSSQL.1 and MSSQL.2 were  installed on a drive the SAN. We are moving away from this SAN do to faults and we wish to move the files and folders to a new SAN. how would we do this?

Edit:
here is a view of the contents.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are `MSSQL.1` and `MSSQL.2`? Folders? What do they contain? Data files, binary files? SQL Server uses version specific folders for its binaries but we are at version 13 right now.

Comment: Are you asking how to move the database files? Did you check the documentation, eg the [Move Database Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189133.aspx) section?

Comment: All database files .mdf and .ndf have all been moved It is just these folders i wish to know how to move.

Comment: That's *definitely* out of scope for Stack Overflow. This isn't related to programming. You should try dba.stackexchange.com. You should understand what you are doing first though, or you'll simply lose all data and binaries. BTW you can't just move mdf and ndf files. The server won't know where to find them if you don't do this *properly*. Are the moved databases working now?

Comment: yes the DB's are all up and running after the move, thanks I will try dba.stackexchange.com and sorry for posting in the wrong area.